Нумерация повторяющихся кадастровых номеров
Имеется огромный список кадастровых номеров и координат участков, лежащих в  txt файле следующего вида:

Нужно пронумеровать дублирующиеся кадастровые номера по типу:

61:07:0000000:3
1   682117,68   2317245,28
2   682113,39   2317252,03
3   682111,07   2317250,56
4   682115,35   2317243,80
S=22 кв.м.

61:07:0000000:3
1   682199,70   2317274,88
2   682201,96   2317275,52
3   682201,28   2317277,98
4   682199,01   2317277,34
S=6 кв.м.
61:07:0000000:6
1   682929,36   2313330,81
2   682931,70   2313330,81
3   682931,70   2313333,37
4   682929,36   2313333,37

Интересно как это можно реализовать.

если меньше гига - загрузи в массив, отсортируй и пройди циктлом - если предыдущий совпадает - пронумеровать

если больше гига, то в скуль и груп бай

вы хотите услышать ответ от людей, которым доводилось нумеровать дублирующиеся кадастровые номера? и потом, вы требуете решения задачи, а не просить помощи с тем, что у вас конкретно не получается.

61:07:0000000:3
1 682117,68 2317245,28
2 682113,39 2317252,03
3 682111,07 2317250,56
4 682115,35 2317243,80
S=22 кв.м.
61:07:0000000:3
1 682199,70 2317274,88
2 682201,96 2317275,52
3 682201,28 2317277,98
4 682199,01 2317277,34
S=6 кв.м.
61:07:0000000:6
1 682929,36 2313330,81
2 682931,70 2313330,81
3 682931,70 2313333,37
4 682929,36 2313333,37
S=6 кв.м.  пример текста, к сожалению не знаю как отформатировать  в этом текстовом поле

Почему пустой строки не хватает?

Читаем входной файл, регулярным выражением выделяем кадастровые номера, считаем их, из дублей делаем словарь, ещё раз читаем входной файл, копируем в выходной нумеруя строки из словаря:
import collections
import re
import sys

cadastral_re = re.compile(r'^\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+\s*$')

in_fname, out_fname = sys.argv[1:]

print('counting...')
with open(in_fname) as f_in:
    c = collections.Counter(filter(cadastral_re.match, f_in))
counters = {k: 0 for k, v in c.items() if v > 1}

print('processing...')
with open(in_fname) as f_in, open(out_fname, 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        if line in counters:
            counters[line] += 1
            line = f'{line[:-1]}/{counters[line]}\n'
        f_out.write(line)

Использование:

$ python number.py in.txt out.txt
counting...
processing...



Я бы не экономил настолько на буквах, что касается c, а в остальном практически идеальный код. Ах да, а вот зря вы filter не любите, можно же короче фильтрацию написать: c = collections.Counter(filter(cadastral_re.match, f_in)) без этих вот line for line in )

@CrazyElf, спасибо! filter теперь будет в моём чемоданчике. И переименовал c -> counters.
